How to make cmdline's tab case insensitive?
I want to know if it is possible to make cmdline's tab case-insensitive?
For example, let's say I would like to use AvanteChat. To achieve this, I would type Avantec<TAB>, which would auto-complete to AvanteC*****.
FYI, I do use lazyvim, which comes with:
ignorecase = true
smartcase = true


In this case, 'smartcase' does exactly what it should do: your input has at least one uppercase character which makes completion default to case-sensitive matches.
This is documented in :help 'smartcase' and :help 'ignorecase'.
There are several ways to work around this:

Input lowercase characters only:
:avantec<Tab>


Use the correct case:
:AvanteC<Tab>


Disable smartcase:
:set nosmartcase
:Avantec<Tab>


Create command-line abbreviations for commonly used commands:
:cabbrev AC AvanteChat
:AC<Space>



Some might find it helpful to have smartcase when searching and nosmartcase when issuing Ex commands.
Unfortunately, I don't know how this could be accomplished.

Turns out, I have misunderstood smartcase! Thank you :)

@ogirginc you're welcome. I see how it might be useful to have : behave one way and / the other way. Maybe a smarter user will find a way and answer.
